# Compute limit of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^n+2^{3n}}{3^n\cdot4^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

> I need help to compute the limit of the following series: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^n+2^{3n}}{3^n\cdot4^n}$

**What I got so far:** 
It is probably easier to split the sum into the following:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^n+2^{3n}}{3^n\cdot4^n}$ = $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^n}{(3\cdot4)^n} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{8^{n}}{(3\cdot4)^n}=$

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{-1}{6})^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{8}{12})^n= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (\frac{1}{6})^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{4}{6})^n  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (\frac{1}{6})^n + \frac{1}{1-\frac{4}{6}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (\frac{1}{6})^n + 3$

**But here im stuck**: I don't know how to deal with the alternating series that looks similar to another geometric series. Help to get further is very appreciated!

Comment: A series is already a limit, $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}f(n)=\lim_{N\to +\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{N}f(n)$, so there is no need to ask for computing *the limit* of a series. You may just ask *how to compute the series ...*

Comment: Deal with it exactly the same way: it *is* a geometric series, with ratio $-1/6$.

Comment: It's $(-1)^n(\frac{1}{6})^n=(-\frac{1}{6})^n$ and continue. And: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$.

Comment: @guestDiego $\frac{18}{5}$ you mean? I got $\frac{27}{7}$  and im positive that's right

Comment: @WhatAMesh. You are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the geometric series
$${\frac {1}{1-x}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }x^{n}\quad {\text{ for }}|x|<1\!$$
and let $x\rightarrow -x$ to get
$${\frac {1}{1+x}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }(-1)^n(x)^{n}\quad {\text{ for }}|x|<1\!$$